# Firestore query returns"Failed to get document because the client is offline." in Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Actually I'm doing multiple calls to Firestore, all of them are working properly, but there is one that is returning `Failed to get document because the client is offline.`

My query is quite simple:

```
fun getUserById(userID: String, onSuccessListener: OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>, onFailureListener: OnFailureListener) {
        Firebase.firestore
            .collection("users")
            .document(userID)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(onSuccessListener)
            .addOnFailureListener(onFailureListener)
    }
```

But the call is returning the failureCallback. The log of the error is as I said before: `Failed to get document because the client is offline.`

Is strange, because is the unique call is launching this error. The other ones, that are more complex are running perfect.

I checked and the document exist in the DB, and the access rules has not been changed.
The app is in google play, and before this build, was working properly, so the google service json file is correct.

Libraries used:

```
//Firebase Core
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
//Firebase Firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:21.4.2'
//Firebase Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0'
//Firebase push notifications
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.4'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would point out that the error is clear on the fact that the issue is the connection to the firestore server and the device.

I think this could be mitigated by using the [Access data offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) feature of Firestore when using it with Firebase, as I see is your use case. Or are you already using it?

I see that the error is intermittent, but as you have pointed out it seems it’s only failing with the “users” collection, could it happen that the collection “users” is not store in the cell phone cache and that’s leading to the mentioned error?